# C# - Add a File as Attachment to Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject, splistitem

I have no more ideas. I want to create a new element to Sharepoint List and adding a file as an attachment. I can create a new element with `ListItem`. But the file will not upload.

I try with `SaveBinaryDirect()` function and with `AttachmentCreationInformation()` class.
If I try I get this exception

> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll (400)

I also connected to the SharePoint Server and looked inside the Windows Logs, but I found nothing.

In my code I add a new `ListItem` with `lLibrary.AddItem(itemCreateInfo)`. With the `ListItem` I create in SharePoint a new element. This Element is in SharePoint Folder. This all works well.

I tried a lot but nothing worked. I need help, please!

Here my complete Code:

```
public bool UploadToSharepoint(string sURL, string sLibrary, string sFolderName, string sTitel, string sDescription, string sFilePath)
    {
        using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(sURL))
        {
            if (!SetCredentialsInClientContext(clientContext))
            {
                return false;
            }

            List lLibrary = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(sLibrary);

            clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web.Lists);
            clientContext.Load(lLibrary, l => l.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sFolderName))
            {
                itemCreateInfo.FolderUrl = lLibrary.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + sFolderName;
            }

            ListItem newItem = lLibrary.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);

            #region Work only with Document list in SharePoint
            //using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sFilePath, FileMode.Open))
            //{
            //    clientContext.Load(lLibrary.RootFolder);
            //    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            //    string fileUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", lLibrary.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, fi.Name);
            //    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileUrl, fs, true);
            //}  // Ende using 'FileStream'
            #endregion

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sFilePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                #region WORK!
                newItem["Title"] = sTitel;
                newItem["Description"] = sDescription;
                newItem.Update();
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                #endregion

                #region SaveBinaryDirect Example NOT WORK
                //using (FileStream strm = new FileInfo(sFilePath).Open(FileMode.Open))
                //{
                //    Uri url = new Uri(sURL);
                //    //Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, url.AbsolutePath + "/Attachments/" + newItem.Id + "/" + fi.Name, strm, true);
                //    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, lLibrary.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Attachments/" + newItem.Id + "/" + fi.Name, strm, true);
                //}

                ////Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, "", fs, true);
                //string serverRelativeUrl = lLibrary.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;
                //Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, serverRelativeUrl, fs, true);
                #endregion

                #region AttachmentCreationInformation Example NOT WORK
                AttachmentCreationInformation attInfo = new AttachmentCreationInformation();
                attInfo.FileName = fs.Name;
                attInfo.ContentStream = fs;
                newItem.AttachmentFiles.Add(attInfo);
                newItem.Update();
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                #endregion
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

EDIT!:

I have made a big mistake. The Sharepoint is 2010.
So the `AttachmentFiles.Add()` function is not working.

I found out that I have to add a service reference and change my code.
Further information can be found at [SharePoint 2010 - Client Object Model - Add attachment to ListItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969810/sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-add-attachment-to-listitem)

But now I get Exception 500. That's why I tried to connect to a Test SharePoint. There I can read the log information with the Message `The list does not exist.
The selected page contains a list that does not exist. The list could have been deleted by another user.`

I do not know what `listName` property I have to specify for the function `AddAttachment()` that the list is found.

My new Code:

```
public bool UploadToSharepoint(string sURL, string sLibrary, string sFolderName, string sTitel, string sDescription, string sFilePath)
    {
        using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(sURL))
        {
            if (!SetzeCredentialsInClientContext(clientContext))
            {
                return false;
            }

            List lLibrary = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(sLibrary);

            clientContext.Load(lLibrary);
            clientContext.Load(lLibrary.RootFolder);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            ListItemCreationInformation listItemCreationInformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sFolderName))
            {
                listItemCreationInformation.FolderUrl = lLibrary.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + sFolderName;
            }

            var newItem = lLibrary.AddItem(listItemCreationInformation);
            newItem["Title"] = sTitel;
            newItem.Update();
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            clientContext.Load(newItem);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            TestSP.ListsSoapClient lsc = new TestSP.ListsSoapClient();

            if (_cbAutorisierung.Checked)
            {
                lsc.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential(tbName.Text, tbPasswort.Text, tbDomain.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                lsc.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            }
            lsc.AddAttachment(sLibrary, newItem["ID"].ToString(), Path.GetFileName(sFilePath), System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(sFilePath));

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/602369/C-pluscodeplustoplusuploadplusdocumentplustoplus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got to work!

The problem was that in the config file `App.Config` the endpoint Adress explicit reference to the Site.

The Part of "config" File:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpsBinding>
    <binding name="ListsSoap">
      <security>
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="Ntlm" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpsBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://TestSharePoint.com/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"
    binding="basicHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="ListsSoap"
    contract="SPRivarkom.ListsSoap" name="ListsSoap" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

At the tag "endpoint" is the Attribute "adress". This contains the adress of the web reference. But the right adress must be `address="https://TestSharePoint.com/TestSite/TestUnderSite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. Have modified how the folder url is formed. Also modified some code related to attachment upload.

In the `sUrl`, please pass the full url of your site collection.

```
var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(sLibrary);
clientContext.Load(list);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

ListItemCreationInformation listItemCreationInformation = null;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sFolderName))
{
    listItemCreationInformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();
    listItemCreationInformation.FolderUrl = string.Format("{0}Lists/{1}/{2}", sURL, sLibrary, sFolderName);
}

var listItem = list.AddItem(listItemCreationInformation);
newItem["Title"] = sTitel;
newItem["Description"] = sDescription;
listItem.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();                

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sFilePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    var attInfo = new AttachmentCreationInformation();
    attInfo.FileName = fs.Name;
    attInfo.ContentStream = fs;                    

    var att = listItem.AttachmentFiles.Add(attInfo);
    clientContext.Load(att);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: Did not Work. I get a exception on line 'clientContext.ExecuteQuery()' after the line 'listItem.Update()'.

Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException' in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll

Additional information: The file or folder name contains characters that are not allowed. Please use a different name.

(Google Translator...)

Comment: Ensure that the path doesnt contain extra forward slashes. It should be like 'https://sitecollurl/test/lists/libraryname/foldername'

Comment: That is already given with my Code. But that is not the real problem.
I want to add an attachment to the ListItem.

Comment: Please check with edited code. Have removed a forward slash in the folder url path. I have tested the above code at my env and its working fine. It creates a list item with attachment

Comment: I  tried it, but it comes to this excaption.
I changed the Code from

'listItemCreationInformation.FolderUrl = string.Format("{0}Lists/{1}/{2}", sURL, sLibrary, sFolderName);'

to
'listItemCreationInformation.FolderUrl = lLibrary.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + sFolderName;'

Because the 'sURL' is like 'https://SP.com/siteexample/example/Lists/Site/FolderExample'.

The code works so that the element is created. As before.

But now I get a new Exception Message:

'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 2, position 1.'